# how to seed data to Riak using REST API from remote host

Tags: rest, curl, riak

I installed riak as per mentioned in the tutorial [riak quick start](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/).

I can upload/seed data to riak as described in REST API using curl client. The example curl commands as follows

```
curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:10018/riak/favs/db \
```

-H "Content-Type: text/html" \
-d "

## My new favorite DB is RIAK

"

The same when I try to GET,

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:10018/riak/favs/db
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Whereas when I try uploading/seeding data from another machine (remote machine) things do not work as expected.

```
curl -i -X GET http://10.0.77.81:10018/riak/stats
```

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

But I could ping the host,

```
ping 10.0.77.81
```

PING 10.0.77.81 (10.0.77.81) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.77.81: icmp_req=1 ttl=61 time=576 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.77.81: icmp_req=1 ttl=61 time=576 ms

Could connect to tomcat server,

```
hariharankumar@pc170233-ThinkCentre-M70e:~/softwares/riak-1.4.2/rel/riak$ curl -i -X GET http://10.0.77.81:8080
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

When connecting to riak host alone curl throws me error saying could not connect to host.

Answer (score 1):

The cluster built in the Riak quick start is intended as a local development cluster and it is therefore by default set up to only accept connections from 127.0.0.1. You can change this in the app.config file for each node, which can be found in the `/etc` directory, and instead make it bind to e.g. 0.0.0.0.